# iOS 5 app termination timestamp?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I need to know when an application was terminated.  I know you can't rely on applicationWillTerminate: being called from a background/suspended state. I did notice that the Snapshots directory (Library/Caches/Snapshots) does get touched when my application does terminate. Then on the subsequent application launch, I can interrogate its modification time.

You may be wondering why I don't just mark the time when the applicationDidEnterBackground: or  applicationWillResignActive: methods fire.  I don't want to count the time the app spends in the background.

This is working, but I wondered if I can rely on this or if there was a better approach (please let there be a better approach).

Thanks!

Comment: But if another application touches the Snapshots directory, the modification time will not be correct for your application.

Comment: It's in my sandbox.  How could another application modify it?

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking of the system directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would try listening for the SIGTERM signal sent to your app prior to exiting. Unfortunately there are strict limits on what your signal handler can do. I can't remember whether you can create a file or not, but I would look into that first since you can check the creation date the next time you launch.

Comment: I think you would have to catch the kill signal (-9) though. According to the header:


#define SIGKILL 9 /* kill (cannot be caught or ignored) */

Comment: I did try catching SIGTERM though with no luck.